# Change partition for Home and create a swapfile

Tags: linux-mint, home-folder

I install Mint 19.3 weeks ago, my first real Linux  My Home is on the same partition than the OS , and i have swap of 2 G on the same partition. I want to move Home to sdb2(ext4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`d suggest to backup the contents of your homefolder to an external hdd and 
a fresh install of the OS with "/home" on sdb. You have to choose 
"something else" when installing.

To create the swapfile you can follow this guide: (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=284100&p=1569661&hilit=fail%20after%20hibernation#p1569661)

You will find there a line "SIZE=4",set the number to the double of your ram.
Be patient,some steps need a little time to be worked down. 
This is always the perfect solution for me.

Comment: thank you but i wont reinstall , i ve been running for a month with that installation and everything go fine until now, my home is empty , I will read the tuto you send me thanks again